# Objective-C and integers outside methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods, int

I have a question regarding integers outside of methods in Objective-C/Xcode. I'm trying to create a simple guessing game, however my randomizer randomize number every time when the method is called, here is the code snipped:

```
    - (IBAction)guessButton:(id)sender {
            int tempUserGuess = [self.textField.text integerValue];
            int randomNumber = (arc4random() % 11);

        if(tempUserGuess == randomNumber){
            self.guessAns.text = @"you won!";
        }
        if (tempUserGuess < randomNumber){
            self.guessAns.text = @"no! too low!";
        }
        if (tempUserGuess > randomNumber){
            self.guessAns.text = @"no! too high!";
        }
    }
```

The reason why I'm trying to put an int outside of the method is of that once randomized integer should not be randomized every single time (of course). By the way, everything works fine, the app compiles and works but every single time when I hit return, it randomizes the number.

I know how to do this in Java, but Objective-C seems to be more complex.

Comment: How will you do it in Java then? Once you got it, the exact same thing can be done in Objective-C... It's clearly not a language issue...

Comment: Why not set the random number before and then compare on the guessButton press? i.e. make randNum an instance variable and set it in a method

Answer (score 2):

Your `guessButton` method is probably a member of some class. You need to add property to that class holding that randomized number.

Answer (score 1):

You only have to create/store a random number once per game play.  There is no need to call the randomize method each time the guess button is pressed.  The guessButton method is basically like an ActionListener in java.  Each time the button is pressed, whatever's inside the curly braces will be executed.  If you add a play again button to the game, then you might want to call the randomize method inside of it's action method.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(tempUserGuess == num){
        self.guessAns.text = @"you won!";
}
```

This will be a good way because it will be using less memory in the sytem when trying to divert the random number. Good work

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got it.
Here is the answer:

in ViewController.h I had to include:

```
    NSInteger num;
```

and then in ViewController.m a method that simply returns a number:

```
    -(int)giveRandom {

        int randomNumber = (arc4random() % 10);
        return randomNumber;
    }
```

And then refer to 'num' in the method with if statements such as:

```
    ...
    if(tempUserGuess == num){
            self.guessAns.text = @"you won!";
    }
    ...
```

For some reason it returns 0, but I will try to solve it.

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you call give random?